# Placing a Polygon using a given set of 3D coordinates in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to draw a polygon (wall) in 3D space with Three.JS but it's proving hard to do.

I want to use `ExtrudeGeometry` as my wall needs thickness. Also, assume there might be anywhere from three to an infinite amount of points so, a simple `BoxGeometry` is not suitable.

Consider this:
[image: Polygon]

Starting from the bottom left and moving clockwise, say these are the coordinates of the green points. Assume given points are always on the same plane.

```
[
  [1, 0, -1],
  [1, 3, -1],
  [5, 3, -4],
  [5, 0, -4],
]
```

It works fine on a 2D plane because `Shape` takes 2D points. Something like this:

```
const shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.lineTo(0, 0);
shape.lineTo(0, 5);
shape.lineTo(5, 5);
shape.lineTo(5, 0);

const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, { steps: 1, depth: 1 });
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The only way I can think of doing this is by rotating my points to a 2D plane to find what the 2D equivalent coordinates would be, then to create the shape then rotate the geometry back to where I want. This seems excessively complicated though and, if my coordinates were rotated about two axes, then that would open another can of worms.

So how can I place a polygon in 3D space given a set of three or more points?

Comment: Have a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-on-dynamically-created-object/2994/8

Comment: You're a legend @prisoner849 . Must've been asking google the wrong questions the last few days to have missed these.

The only issue I'm having (just testing with `ShapeGeometry`) is getting it back to the original position. I'm guessing that is the purpose of `mesh.geometry.vertices = points` right before adding it to the scene except it doesn't look like it works for the sample or my implementation. I created a `reverseQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(baseNormal, normal)` to get it back to the correct orientation but its position is still off.

Answer (score 2):

First part of answer is here at the top of the discourse:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-on-dynamically-created-object/2994
like @prisoner849 described in the comment.

But also before applying `reverseQuaternion` you need to know, that when you create `Shape`, every Z coordinate of `ShapeGeometry` will be 0 by default, because of `Shape` constructor uses `Vector2[]` value, not `Vector3[]`. So you need to update it with real Z coordinate after first applying of quaternion:

```
const tempPoints = [];
points.forEach(p => {
  tempPoints.push(p.clone().applyQuaternion(quaternion));
});
const z = tempPoints[0].z; // z coordinate will be the same for every point
const shape = new Shape(tempPoints); // but it will be used as Vector2[] values, not Vector3[] values
```

... then apply this Z to every vertice:

```
const geometry = new ShapeGeometry(shape);
const position: Float32BufferAttribute = geometry.attributes['position'];
for (let i = 0; i < position.array.length; i++) {
  position.setZ(i, z);
}
position.needsUpdate = true;
```

... and then you need apply `reverseQuaternion` on this geometry or mesh with that geometry and you will get your mesh with right position.